# Why is my BubbleSort algorithm working in Java but not in Python

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

Why does this code seem to work:

```
package de.Algos;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort {
    public static int[] swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
        int temp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = temp;
        return A;
    }

    public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] A){
        int n = A.length;
        for(int i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=n-2-i;j++){
                if(A[j]>A[j+1]){
                    swap(A,j,j+1);
                }
            }
        }
        return A;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] A = {12,3,4,5,24,5,3,35352,24,13513513,33};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        A = bubbleSort(A);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }
}
```

[image: Java Output]

While my translation to Python doesn't:

```
# currently not working yet

def swap(A, a, b): 
    A[a], A[b] = A[b], A[b]
    return A

def bubbleSort(A, n):
    for i in range(0,n-1,1):
        for j in range(0,n-1-i,1):
            if A[j] > A[j+1]:
                A = swap(A,j,j+1)
                display(f'Swapped {A[j]} at {j} with {A[j+1]} at {j+1}')
    return A
```

```
A = [0, 1, 4, 25, 5, 745, 253264, 3]
display(A)
A = bubbleSort(A, len(A))
display(A)
```

[image: Python Output]

Which stupid mistake did I make?

I really can't find it.
Maybe it is in the for functions in Python via range behaving differently? Is there any more elegant solution you can make up to make it look as close to the pseudocode given?

```
BubbleSort(A, n)
for i←0 to n-2 {
 for j←0 to n-2-i {
 if (A[j] > A[j+1]) {
     swap(A, j, j+1)
 }
 }
}
```

Kind regards and thanks,

Comment: `A[a], A[b] = A[b], A[b]`. Too many `b`s.

Comment: Woow thanks small mistake big impact :)

Comment: Yes. Notice how your printouts says "Swapped 3 at ... with 3 at ...". From there, you could have checked what `A` was before and after `swap`, and that would have lead you to `swap` being the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your `swap` method definition in python is not the same as in Java.

In Java you're indeed swapping the A[j] and A[j+1]. In Python, there's no swap as A[j] = A[j+1] but A[j+1] remains the same. Try:

```
def swap(A, a, b): 
    A[a], A[b] = A[b], A[a]
    return A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def swap(A, a, b): 
    A[a], A[b] = A[b], A[a]
    return A
```

your swap function isn't right.
at first, the right side takes the values and then save them in the left - not ordering, A[a] = A[b] and then A[b] = A[b] which you think is already A[a]... if I was clear... hard to say with words.

Answer (score 0):

Working Python solution now is:

```py
def swap(A, a, b):
    A[a], A[b] = A[b], A[a]
    return A

def bubbleSort(A, n):
    for i in range(0,n-1,1):
        for j in range(0,n-1-i,1):
            if A[j] > A[j+1]:
                A = swap(A,j,j+1)
                display(f'Swapped {A[j]} at {j} with {A[j+1]} at {j+1}')
    return A
```